# For each Loop Will Not Work Search for Value On one Sheet and Change Value on another Sheet

Tags: excel, for-loop, foreach, vba

I have a list of true and false values on sheet 3 column A and a list of codes on sheet 2 Column A. If the value on sheet 3 A5 is = True then I want the value on sheet 2 A5 should be colored red. And If the value on sheet 3 A6 is = True then I want the value on sheet 2 A6 should be colored red. And this should move down along Column A on sheet 2 and sheet 3 until data runs out. So far i have got it to work for the first cell in column A but can not get the For Each loop to work. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub compare_cols()

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim lastCell As Long

    'Get the last row
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range

    Set c = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A5:25")
    Set d = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5:25")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     For Each cell In c
     For Each cell In d

            If c.Value = True Then
            d.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If

Next
Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: When I faced this problem I have overcome it with replacing first for loop with while loop. You can try that if you like. However more convenient answer already given below i guess :)

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient solution wouldn't necessarily next 2 loops within each other. Instead, loop through the range that you'd like to check, and reference the cells `Address` property to identify new cells to highlight.

Check the code below and let me know if you understand it

```
Sub ColorOtherSheet()
    Dim wsCheck As Worksheet
    Dim wsColor As Worksheet
    Dim rngLoop As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range

    Set wsCheck = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set wsColor = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngLoop = Intersect(wsCheck.UsedRange, wsCheck.Columns(1))

    For Each rngCell In rngLoop
        If rngCell.Value = True Then
            wsColor.Range(rngCell.Address).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next rngCell


End Sub
```