# Searching Range Sheet1 Against Range in Sheet2 Copy to Sheet3 depending on value in lateral cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched and found a number of posts that are similar for instance

[Look for values from sheet A in sheet B, and then do function in corresponding sheet B cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177975/look-for-values-from-sheet-a-in-sheet-b-and-then-do-function-in-corresponding-s)
and
[For each Loop Will Not Work Search for Value On one Sheet and Change Value on another Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152768/for-each-loop-will-not-work-search-for-value-on-one-sheet-and-change-value-on-an)

While each of these address some aspect of my goal they are not quite it. 
I have 3 sheets, sheet1 - 3, I want to search and match in sheets1 - 2 on columns A and B, if a match is found or not found in column B check value in column A to copy to sheet3 or not.

This is what I have so far using Office 2016.

```
Public Sub SeekFindCopyTo()

Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim tempVal As String

lastRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For sRow = 4 To lastRow1
    Debug.Print ("sRow is " & sRow)
    tempVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sRow, "B").Text

    For tRow = 4 To lastRow2
        Debug.Print ("tRow is " & tRow)
        TestVal = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tRow, "B")
        Operations = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tRow, "A")

        If Sheets("SAP_XMATTERS").Cells(tRow, "B") = tempVal Then
            Operations = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tRow, "A")
            Debug.Print ("If = True tempVal is " & tempVal)
            Debug.Print ("If = True TestVal is " & TestVal)
            Debug.Print ("If = True Operaitons is " & Operations)
            If Operations = "REMOVE" Then
                 Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & tRow).EntireRow.Copy
                 Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert xlcutcell
                 'Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(tRow).Delete
            Else
                 'Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(tRow).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next tRow
Next sRow
End Sub
```

The code works well enough but the catch is that I am looking for a match in B:B between Sheets 1&2 if match I want to check the adjacent cell in A:A for the string REMOVE if it is REMOVE then copy entire row to sheet3. Here's the problem I also want to know if there is not a match in B:B between Sheets 2 & 1 with the string PROCESS in adjacent cell if so copy entire row to sheet3. I can do either option in separate subs but cannot make it work in one pass.

Your help would be appreciated even if it is along the lines of "you can't do that" ;-)

TIA

Bob

Comment: A quick note - always qualify your ranges with the sheet. You do this almost everywhere, but check your `lastRow1 = ...` and `lastRow2 = ...`, where you have `Rows.Count`, put the sheet you want to count on in there. Otherwise, ***both*** `lastRow1` and `lastRow2` will use the active sheet's `Rows.Count`.  (Also you do this later, in your `If Operations = "Remove" ...` loop).

Comment: Sample data could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A total re-write using .Find did the trick.

```
Sub SeekFindCopy()
    Dim sourceValue As Variant
    Dim resultOfSeek As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range

    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B")

    For sourceRow = 4 To LastRow
    Debug.Print ("sRow is " & sRow)

    sourceValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & sRow).Value

    Set resultOfSeek = targetRange.Find(what:=sourceValue, After:=targetRange(1))
        'Debug.Print (sourceValue)
    Operations = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sRow, "A")
    If resultOfSeek Is Nothing Then
            'Debug.Print ("Operations is " & Operations)
        If Operations = "PROCESS" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & sRow).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("UpLoad").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert xlcutcell
            'Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(tRow).Delete
        End If
    Else
            'Debug.Print ("Operations is " & Operations)
        If Operations = "REMOVE" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & sRow).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("UpLoad").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert xlcutcell
            'Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(tRow).Delete
        End If
    End If
    Next sourceRow
End Sub
```